# Google chrome v 105 cookie changes

Tags: google-chrome, delphi, encryption, cookies

i use a decryption method to decrypt the encrypted_value from the google chrome's cookie's database for certain records.
This worked very well until version 104, now with version 105 decrypting it using BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider, BCryptSetProperty and on BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey it returns value -1073741811 while it should return 0, i am unsure which changes they made to the cookies value and can't find information about it.

Does anyone have any hints on what's changed?

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, i found the reason, i am using the os_crypt value from the local state file to do the decryption, which is a json file, and i see that the
os_crypt key now has 2 subkeys "app_bound_fixed_data" and "encrypted_key"

So i need to change my json read method and look for the subkey if it exists.